# SQL Server localization

Tags: sql-server-2008, localization, globalization

Does SQL Server take over the localization from the server it's installed on? Or can you define the locale for each instance/database?

Which setting is responsible for having comma or period when a double is saved to the database?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server has a server collation and each database can either use the server collation or can be set to a different collation.

The format of the datatype will be taken from the Database collation.  Providing that a collation has not been explicitly set for the column.

[SQL Server Collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if you use different collation for columns that you are trying to compare, you will need to use COLLATE and that will cause the argument to be a "non searchable argument", that is indexes will not be used to satisfy that statement.